# How to represent time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

HTML5 form input element provides a way to enter only time. What is the best way to represent that time then in a JavaScript object which could be manipulated in a similar way one can manipulate datetime objects with moment.js? If I use moment.js to parse only time, like `moment('12:13:14', 'HH:mm:ss')`, it is added current date to the value. So it is not possible to know that in fact the object represents only time. So if you later want to work with the object, you do not know if that is date or time.

Comment: The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object has hours, minutes, and seconds, along with having the date.

Comment: You could set the date to 0000/01/01 to identify it as a time-only object; unless that would be a valid date for your purposes, in which case the year 9999 should be safe enough.  Very hacky, though.

Comment: if you just want time, just use the time functions of the date object, and ignore the date ones.